# Graphite - use multiple series with DivideSeries

Tags: python, graphite, click-through

I'm trying to use Graphite to compute a CTR for all my resources, so I tried recording my data like this:

- ctr.resource_id.clicks
- ctr.resource_id.reach

So first, I made my query :

```
&target= averageSeries(divideSeries(ctr.176983011340976128.clicks,ctr.176983011340976128.reach),divideSeries(ctr.190348137012011008.clicks,ctr.190348137012011008.reach))
```

My problem here is that I don't want to send all my resource ids to graphite, so I tried :

```
&target= averageSeries(divideSeries(ctr.*.clicks,ctr.*.reach))
```

But yeah, as the [documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.divideSeries) says "*ValueError: divideSeries second argument must reference exactly 1 series*".

I tried an alternative architecture :

- ctr.clicks.resource_id
- ctr.reach.resource_id

But same problem…

I'm new with Graphite, so if anyone has a solution, it will be amazing!

Edit:

Just saw the function [groupByNode](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode), trying to use it…

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to aggregate your data into a series beforehand so you can pass it to divideSeries.

Aggregator-rules.conf reference in the Configuring Carbon docs: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html

So you'd need 2 rules like this to sum up the click data per min:
ctr.resource_all.clicks (60) = sum ctr.*.clicks
ctr.resource_all.reach (60) = sum ctr.*.reach

You'll also have to run the carbon-aggregator.py daemon
`/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-aggregator.py start`

The default port for the aggregator daemon is 2023, so that's where you should send your traffic instead of the 2003 port you've been using.